# Array section arithmetic in Fortran90

Tags: arrays, fortran, sections

This code fragment:

```
real*8 a(20,5,2)
real*8 b(5)
real*8 c(20,5,2)

! define a vals ....

! define b vals ....

c(1:20, :, 1:2) = a(1:20,:,1:2)*b
```

won't compile because `b` doesn't have the same shape as `a` or `c`.  I, of course, want the five values of `b` to match to the 5 values of the middle indices of `a` and `c`, but the Fortran compiler doesn't understand this.  Is there some way to tell it what I want here?  I know I could replicate `b` in a larger array to match the shape of `a` and `c` but that wastes memory.  I could also put the whole thing in loops but for the actual code I am trying to write that will be cumbersome.  Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Are you looking for numpy-like broadcasting?

Comment: @ptb Well, that wasn't exactly what I was thinking.  But now that you mention it, yeah, something like that.

Comment: You could look up the `spread` intrinsic (I've never actually used it) but it's unlikely that anything will outperform simple `do` loops.  If you get it to work both ways, I would be interested in your timing results.

Comment: how is `a(1:20,:,1:2)` different from `a(1:20,1:5,1:2)` Both just the whole array no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that Fortran is either preventing you shooting yourself in the foot, or, if you prefer, insisting that you be clear about what array elements you want to multiply.  The expression

```
 a(1:20,:,1:2)
```

is a section of 40 elements for each value of the 2nd index.  It's not at all clear what the 5 elements of `b` are to multiply.

I suspect that you are looking for the `spread` function which is the one to use to 'uprank' an array.  Without clarification it's kind of difficult to propose an appropriate application of `spread`, perhaps if you explain further you'll get a better answer than this one.

Heck, let's go ahead without clarification ...

I interpret OP's intention to be to compute the elements of `c` thusly:

```
  DO ix = 1,5
     c(:,ix,:) = a(:,ix,:)*b(ix)
  END DO
```

which can be replaced by

```
  c = a * SPREAD(SPREAD(b,dim=1,ncopies=20),dim=3,ncopies=2)
```

I've given this only very limited testing, the lesson is perhaps to follow @ptb's advice to stick to `do` loops.

Comment: Consider the order of array element access given the choice of indexed dimension for the example do loop.